# RF output matching using baluns: LTC6946

Tags: differential, impedance-matching, single-ended, balun

The datasheet that I refer to below can be found here:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6946fb.pdf

I have a question about baluns. In the datasheet for LTC6946 integer-N synthesizer, the manufacturer recommends that the RF+/RF- output port be driven differentially. However, they also include the option to drive it single ended. They then include a table (on page 26) titled "**single-ended** RF output impedance." Why do they specifically say single-ended? If I wanted to transform the RF+/RF- differential ports to single ended using a balun, would I still need to do the impedance matching? If so, how would I do  that?

As a side note, I would like to get RF frequencies of approx 400 MHz and 900 MHz out of the device, but it only mentions output impedance for 500 and 1000 ohms. If I was to design a matching circuit, would I just use the matching for 500 and 1000 and say "close enough, good enough"?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why do they specifically say single-ended?*

They are referring to each of the two RF outputs individually. In other words, at 500 MHz, each RF output has an impedance of 102.8 Ω - j49.7 Ω.

> *If I wanted to transform the RF+/RF- differential ports to single
> ended using a balun, would I still need to do the impedance matching?
> If so, how would I do that?*

Matching the impedances is all part of designing a balun circuit. I can't tell you how to do that without knowledge of what impedance you require. However, the data sheet does give recommendations: -

[image]

These recommendations will be for a 50 Ω output.

> *As a side note, I would like to get RF frequencies of approx 400 MHz
> and 900 MHz out of the device*

Looks like you should choose the first balun mentioned in the list. If you want to dig deeper you should get a data sheet for the balun specified and look at what its performance is.

Comment: Hi Andy, I require a 50 ohm single-ended output. How would I go about transforming the impedance from what they state to the 50 ohms after the balun? Since each input has impedance of 102.8-j49.7, does that mean that across the differential port, the impedance is 205.6-j99.4? Also, the frequencies I'm trying to get out are actually 433.92 MHz and 915 MHz, so would that first balun mentioned be ok? I've got a balun that covers a wider frequency range so that bit shouldn't be an issue, but I'm still not sure how to do impedance matching correctly with a balun present as well.

Comment: @jerrybenny18 yes the impedance doubles when driving with both outputs. The first balun is recommended for 350 to 900 MHz so it may not be as optimum as one specifically designed for 915 MHz (3rd one). If you want the theory of impedance matching and how to use tuned circuits to achieve step-up or step-down impedance matching then that makes your question too broad to answer. [Link to impedance matching site theory](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20home.html).

Comment: @jerrybenny18 to understand the motivation behind people giving help and advice for free please [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)